# Bootstrap dropdown: working on text, not buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can easily use Bootstrap to create a button dropdown such as the following:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">Action</button>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   content goes here
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, this creates a button and block element (?).

Is it possible to use Bootstrap's button dropdwon to create normal text (best to be inline), clicking on which produces a dropdown?

I am not talking about Bootstrap tooltip. I am hoping to use the dropdown to hold a more complex layout.

Thanks for any idea or suggestion!

Comment: What kind of layout ?can you give an example?

Comment: layout will include text, checkboxes, and radio buttons. Just a small control panel with options.

Comment: You can have almost anything in in that ul.dropdown-menu but the problem is probably it's not going to work as you expect it.Using a custom JS to handle this would be an elegant solution not bootstrap dropdown

Comment: codedme, thanks for your input. I could use qTip and some other tool for this. However, I hope to be able to use Bootstrop for it. I dont want to use more tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a link instead of a button to toggle the dropdown? use this markup:

```
<div class="dropdown"> 
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        You can add any content here
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can also add

```
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To make it appear inline